# Solicitar nuevo dato al estar erroneo, try - catch

Tags: java, while, try-catch

Soy novato en java y estoy haciendo un programa que realice una división y al momento de ingresar un 0 o un numero con punto decimal marque error y lo muestre en pantalla con try-catch. Lo que no se como hacer es que al momento que el usuario digite esas dos opciones erróneas, le vuelva a pedir que digite un numero diferente.

```
 try{
        System.out.println("--D I V I S I O N--");
        System.out.print("Ingrese el numerador: ");
        numerador = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ingrese el denominador: ");
        denominador = scanner.nextInt();
        resultado = numerador / denominador;
        System.out.println("El resultado es: "+resultado);
    }catch(ArithmeticException ex){
        System.out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage()+", No se puede dividir entre '0'");
    }catch(InputMismatchException ms){
        System.out.println("Error: "+ms.getMessage()+", El caracter tiene que se un numero entero...");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Fin del programa... ");
    }
```

Comment: Idea general: Mete el try/catch dentro de un bucle; mientras una variable booleana sea *false* no saldrá del bucle. Dentro del try, si se llega al final y no ha saltado excepción, se pone esa variable a true para que ya no se repita el bucle.

Answer (score 0):

Hola no me convence mucho usar ciclos ya que pueden llegar a alentar el resultado de programa, he aquí una solución más liviana y no he hecho más que agregar un método el cual estaría auto-llamándose en caso de algún error.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        division(); 
    }
    
    public static void division(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            System.out.println("--D I V I S I O N--");
            System.out.print("Ingrese el numerador: ");
            int numerador = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese el denominador: ");
            int denominador = scanner.nextInt();
            int resultado = numerador / denominador;
            System.out.println("El resultado es: "+resultado);
        }catch(ArithmeticException ex){
            System.out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage()+", No se puede dividir entre '0'");
            division(); //De tú código solo agregue esto, aquí se vuelve a llamar el método en caso de que exista el error
        }catch(InputMismatchException ms){
            System.out.println("Error: "+ms.getMessage()+", El caracter tiene que se un numero entero...");
            division(); //De tú código solo agregue esto, aquí se vuelve a llamar el método en caso de que exista el error
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Fin del programa... ");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres alentar el resultado del programa? En este caso no necesitas usar recursividad. Cada vez que el usuario ingrese un dato erróneo, se crea una pila de llamada de forma innecesaria. Lo ideal sería usar bucles.